# Is output key class or value class mandatory or optional in Hadoop job?

Tags: java, hadoop

In a single class MapReduce job in Java, do I have to set the output key class or value class, or it optional and there is some sort of default that applies if it is not set?  For instance, if I comment out the following in my job, it appears to run fine, but I just want to confirm I am not missing anything.

Lines in question to comment out...

```
//job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
//job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

Sample data file, which I split on the comma and pull in first an last column...

```
600000US00601,00601,"00601 5-Digit ZCTA; 006 3-Digit ZCTA",11102
8600000US00602,00602,"00602 5-Digit ZCTA; 006 3-Digit ZCTA",12869
8600000US00603,00603,"00603 5-Digit ZCTA; 006 3-Digit ZCTA",12423
8600000US00604,00604,"00604 5-Digit ZCTA; 006 3-Digit ZCTA",33548
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we need to set the output key/value class explicitly in the Hadoop program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461249/why-do-we-need-to-set-the-output-key-value-class-explicitly-in-the-hadoop-progra)

Answer (score 2):

From Hadoop definitive guide [ Ed 3rd / ch 7.3 ] :

```
Text Output
The default output format, TextOutputFormat, writes records as lines of text. Its keys 
and values may be of any type, since TextOutputFormat turns them to strings by calling 
toString() on them. Each key-value pair is separated by a tab character, although that 
may be changed using the mapred.textoutputformat.separator property.
```

It states `TextOutputFormat` calls `toString()` on both key & value when outputting and thus can accept any type. So I think it won't create any problem on running simple MR jobs without specifying the lines you mentioned.

However, it will certainly create problem when you specify another output format explicitly, say `SimpleDBOutpFormat` for example.